# how to get global variable value in .each function of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to update the global variable, inside a .each function but it is not working

```
var ctc_change=0;
$('.table'+employeeid+ ' thead th').each(function(e, ctc_change){
        ctc_change++;
    }
});
```

Comment: Don't call the second parameter of the `each` callback function `ctc_change` maybe? And you have a typo there

Comment: In general, if you want to access a global variable, don't use the same name for a local variable.

Comment: BTW, you have the arguments to the function backwards. The arguments to `.each()` are `index, element` -- it's annoyingly the opposite of JavaScript `forEach()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var ctc_change=0;
$('.table'+employeeid+ ' thead th').each(function(e, ctc_change){
        ctc_change++;
    }
});
```

You have to rename the local variable from your function as

```
var ctc_change=0;
$('.table'+employeeid+ ' thead th').each(function(e, ctc){
        ctc_change++;
    }
});
```

Your incrementation in the function refers the local variable